# How to loop through elements of forms with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form:

```
<form method="POST" action="submit.php">
    <input type="text" value="1">
    <input type="text" value="2">
    <input type="text" value="3">
    <input type="text" value="4">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

How can I loop over the input elements in the form (in order to perform some validation on them)?

I'd prefer to use only pure JavaScript, not jQuery or another library. I'd also like to limit the iteration to form elements, not any other elements which may be added to the form.

Comment: try yourFormElement.getElementsByTagName

Comment: @DanDascalescu As you can see in the HTML, _these_ form field doesn't have different names. Thus, it is _not_ duplicate.

Answer (score 61):

A modern ES6 approach. The form has a property `elements` which is a reference to all the input elements. Select the form with any method you like. Use the spread operator to convert the `HTMLFormControlsCollection` to an Array. Then the `forEach` method is available. For example `[...form.elements].forEach`

Update: `Array.from` is a nicer alternative to the spread operator `Array.from(form.elements)` it's slightly clearer behaviour.

---

An example below iterates over every input in the form.

You can filter out input types with the type property `formInputs.filter((input) => input.type !== "submit")`

```js
const forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
const form = forms[0];

Array.from(form.elements).forEach((input) => {
  console.log(input);
});
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Input Form Selection</h1>
  <form>
    <label>
      Foo
      <input type="text" placeholder="Foo" name="Foo" />
    </label>
    <label>
      Password
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
    </label>
    <label>
      Foo
      <input type="text" placeholder="Bar" name="Bar" />
    </label>
    <span>Ts &amp; Cs</span>
    <input type="hidden" name="_id" />
    <input type="submit" name="_id" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: querySelector for single queries, e.g `[...document.querySelector('form').elements].forEach(el => ...);`

Comment: imo, the spread operate reads just as nice.

Answer (score 59):

You need to get a reference of your form, and after that you can iterate the `elements` collection. So, assuming for instance:

```
<form method="POST" action="submit.php" id="my-form">
  ..etc..
</form>
```

You will have something like:

```
var elements = document.getElementById("my-form").elements;

for (var i = 0, element; element = elements[i++];) {
    if (element.type === "text" && element.value === "")
        console.log("it's an empty textfield")
}
```

Notice that in browser that would support querySelectorAll you can also do something like:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("#my-form input[type=text][value='']")
```

And you will have in `elements` just the element that have an empty value attribute. Notice however that if the value is changed by the user, the attribute will be remain the same, so this code is only to filter by attribute not by the object's property. Of course, you can also mix the two solution:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("#my-form input[type=text]")

for (var i = 0, element; element = elements[i++];) {
    if (element.value === "")
        console.log("it's an empty textfield")
}
```

You will basically save one check.

Comment: Beware this CSS selector will miss input with no attributes, even though they'll default to `"text"`, this will not be reflected at the attribute level. There should be an other selector targetting `input:not([type])` along with it.

Comment: @Kaiido: It's also worth noting that HTML5 added [a bunch of new input element types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Form_%3Cinput%3E_types), several of which are basically just text boxes with extra input validation.

Comment: imo it's unnecessary compacting that you add to the iterator in the array index, when you could just put the addition i++ after the semicolon where it belongs. for(i=0; el=array[i]; i++), and if you should be really nitpicking to use the assignment of element as the loop termination check is also not pretty. i < elements.length is simpler code, even though you need to put the assignment inside the for loop instead. Nothing wrong coding like that for yourself but in examples for others, it complicates and might confuse new coders.

Answer (score 15):

You can use [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByTagName) function, it returns a HTMLCollection of elements with the given tag name.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("input")
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    if(elements[i].value == "") {
        alert('empty');
        //Do something here
    }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zE4MK/)

You can also use `document.myform.getElementsByTagName` provided you have given a name to yoy form

[**DEMO with form Name**](http://jsfiddle.net/2daFp/)

Comment: all inputs in document? not good idea. this method exist for specified element

Comment: To avoid pulling all inputs in the document, `.getElementsByTagName("input")` can be applied to the form object or any other block object like a div.

Comment: There's also a button in that form, would "inputs" get that button?

Answer (score 9):

You can iterate named fields somehow like this:

```
let jsonObject = {};
for(let field of form.elements) {
  if (field.name) {
      jsonObject[field.name] = field.value;
  }
}
```

Or, if you need only submiting fields:

```
function formDataToJSON(form) {
  let jsonObject = {};
  let formData = new FormData(form);
  for(let field of formData) {
      jsonObject[field[0]] = field[1];
  }
  return JSON.stringify(jsonObject);
}
```

Comment: Or you can just filter them: `[...form.elements].filter(e=>e.name)`

Answer (score 3):

Es5 forEach:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(form.elements, function (inpt) {
       if(inpt.name === name) {
             inpt.parentNode.removeChild(inpt);
       }
});
```

Otherwise the lovely for:

```
var input;
for(var i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++) {
     input = form.elements[i];

      // ok my nice work with input, also you have the index with i (in foreach too you can get the index as second parameter (foreach is a wrapper around for, that offer a function to be called at each iteration.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<form id="yourFormName" >
<input type="text" value="" id="val1">
<input type="text" value="" id="val2">
<input type="text" value="" id="val3">
<button type="button" onclick="yourFunction()"> Check </button>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function yourFunction()
{
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll("#yourFormName input[type=text]")
  console.log(elements);
  for (var i = 0; i<elements.length; i++ )
  {
    var check = document.getElementById(elements[i].id).value);
    console.log(check);
    // write your logic here
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
    $('form button').click(function() {
        var allowSubmit = true;
        $.each($('form input:text'), function(index, formField) {
            if($(formField).val().trim().length == 0) {
                alert('field is empty!');
                allowSubmit = false;
            }
        });
        return allowSubmit;
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/xR47a/6/)

Comment: jQuery? See the OP.