# looping through form elements to validate select type

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to loop through the select elements of the `displayResults` form to check if an option is chosen for each dropdown. Unfortunately, regardless whether any options are chosen or not, the form is submitted to the server.

```
//Validates that form elements are not empty
function validateForm()
{
    for(var i=0; i < document.displayResults.elements.length; i++)
    {
        if(document.displayResults.elements[i].type=="select")
        {
            var test = document.displayResults.elements[i].value;
            if(test = null || test == "")
            {
                alert("Please select appropriate options");
                return false;
            }

        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: is `elements` the name of the select tag?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to loop through elements of forms with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19978600/how-to-loop-through-elements-of-forms-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
//Validates that form elements are not empty
function validateForm()
{
    var displayResults = document.getElementById("displayResults").elements;
    for(var i=0; i < displayResults.length; i++)
    {
        if(displayResults[i].tagName=="SELECT")
        {
            var test = displayResults[i].value;
            if(!test) //This is essentially the same way you did
            {
                alert("Please select appropriate options");
                return false;
            }

        }
    }
    return true;
}
```