# Loop through all the text boxes in an HTML page and replace ones with a certain value with 0's

Tags: html

How to loop through all the text boxes in an HTML page and replace ones with a certain value with 0's.

Comment: "Text boxes" is vague.
What do you mean, textarea, input[type="text"], or what?
How do you intend to replace with "0's"?
One zero? Two? 10? According to the length of their current content?

Comment: Maybe use something based on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19978600/how-to-loop-through-elements-of-forms-with-javascript. You could find some answers and combine them by googling for a couple of minutes..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQuery really does it in a nice fashion. This code replaces text inside any text typed input element inside the form which has "?" in it with "0.00"

`$(document).ready(
        function(){ $("input[type='text'][value*='?']").val("0.00");});`

Answer (score 1):

If you use jQuery, you can use

```
$("input[type='text']").filter(idx, elm)
{
   return $(elm).val() == "YOUR_WANTED_VALUE";
}).val("0");
```

Comment: should I call such function on body load?