# How do i link input submitted text to javascript code

Tags: javascript, html

My html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Huffman Coding</title>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
    <span>Huffman <span>Coding</span></span>
    <br><br><br>
    <div id="temp">
        Enter input string here <br><br><br>
        <form action="" id="input">
            <input id="input-string" name="input_string" type="search">
            <br>
            <button type="submit" onclick="calcHash()">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <p id="demo"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

My Js code:

function calcHash() {

```
var input = document.getElementById("input");

var text = "";
for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    text += input.element[i].value + "<br>";
}

document.getElementsByTagName("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

}

Right now the js file is returning and displaying data into the url instead of the page
I want to print text from input tag into js file and print it back into `<p id="demo"></p>`

---

here's my CSS code also

```
body{
    display: flex; 
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: black;
}
body span{
    font-size: 4rem;
    margin-top: 10rem;
    color: rgb(255, 123, 123);
}
body span span{
    color: rgb(220, 248, 96);
}
div{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

form{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

#input-string{
    background-color: white;
    opacity: 1;
    width: 20rem;
    height: 3rem;
    font-size: large;
}

#submit{
    width: 4rem;
    height: 1.2rem;
}

#output{
    color: aliceblue;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to display the value of `text` in `<p id="demo"></p>`?

Answer (score 0):

code error: **document.getElementsByTagName("demo").innerHTML = text;**
(document.getElementsByTagName)Method returns a collection of objects with the specified tag name

code correct: document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to iterate form elements, use this approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/19978872/11374441

"submit" type button will submit all information in the form which is the reason you see it in the URL. However if your onclick function(calcHash here) returns false, it will not submit the form. So, if you do want to see the info in the URL(i.e. not to submit the form) just make sure your calling function returns false.